# Locus of complex numbers $z$ with restricted $(z+1-i)/(z-1-i)$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

#### Problem

> Describe the locus of the following points on the Argand diagram:
>
> $$\left|\frac{(z+1-i)}{(z-1-i)}\right| = 1$$ and
>
> $$\mathrm{arg}\left[\frac{(z+1+i)}{(z-1-i)}\right] = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

#### Progress

I've tried putting $z = x+iy $ then rationalising the denominator by multiplying by the conjugate which gave me some numbers, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

I would really love some help on these 2 questions, all responses much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you confused with some particular step? It helps for us to know. Regards

Comment: I've tried putting z = x+iy then rationalising the denominator by multiplying by the conjugate which gave me some numbers, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

to answer the second one $$arg\left({z + 1 + i \over z - 1 -i} \right) = \pm {\pi \over 2}$$  is a circle with diameter $1+i, -1-i.$

here is how you can see this: let $${z + 1 + i \over z - 1 -i} = ki \text{  where $k$  is a real number}$$
you can dove for $z$  and get 
$$z = {-ki +k - 1 -i\over 1 -ki} = {[k-1 -i(k+1)] \over 1 - ik} = {[k-1 -i(k+1)](1 + ik) \over 1 + k^2}
\\= {k-1 + k(k+1) + i[k(k-1)-(k+1)] \over 1 + k^2} = {k^2+ 2k - 1 + i(k^2 - 2k - 1)  \over 1 + k^2}$$

if $z = x = iy,$ then $$x = {k^2 - 1 + 2k \over k^2 + 1}, y = {k^2 - 1 - 2k \over k^2 + 1} $$  which gives $$x^2 + y^2 = { 2(k^2 - 1)^2 + 8k^2 \over (k^2 + 1)^2} 
= { 2(k^2 + 1)^2  \over (k^2 + 1)^2}  = 2$$ as claimed at the beginning.

if you look at the geometry of the problem, it says the angle subtended by the point $z$ by the points $\pm(1+i)$ is $90^\circ$ which is the locus of a circle. to derive it algebraically i had to go through all the trouble.

Comment: Yes, it is this circle, but except the two points (0 in denominator is clear; 0 in numerator gives zero which does not have an argument)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is saying that the distance between $z$ and $1 + i$ is the same as the distance between $z$ and $1 - i$. The set of points equidistant from two points is the line bisecting the line segment joining the two points. Hence, the locus is the line $y = 0$.

The second one is saying if you look at the point $P$ given by translating $z$ 1 up and 1 to the right and the point $Q$ given by $z$ translated 1 down and 1 to the left, the angle between $P$ and $Q$ (with respect to the origin) is $\pi/2$. Intuitively, this seems to me to be the line $y = x$, though I haven't checked this rigorously.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanations, so for the first question it's simply the line x=0? Also, for the second question, I thought the angle was always taken between the positive direction of the horizontal - so from which point would we take the angle (does it matter)?

Comment: Ooops, I meant $y = 0$, but yes, that's the answer. As for the second one, arg of a quotient is the angle between the numerator and the denominator. (Because multiplying two complex numbers results in the angles that they make with the positive horizontal axis being added)

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{(z+1-i)}{(z-1-i)}\right| = 1$$
$$\left|\ (z+1-i)\right| = |(z-1-i)|$$
put z=x+iy
$$\left|\ (x+iy+1-i)\right| = |(x+iy-1-i)|$$
$$\left|\ (x+1)+i(y-1)\right| = |(x-1)+i(y-1)|$$
$$\left|\ (x+1)+i(y-1)\right|^2 = |(x-1)+i(y-1)|^2$$
since $$\left|\ (x+iy)\right|^2 = x^2+y^2$$
then
$$\left|\ (x+1)+i(y-1)\right|^2 = |(x-1)+i(y-1)|^2$$
$$
(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2
$$
$$(x+1)^2=(x-1)^2$$
$$x=0$$
equation of Y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

On the Argand diagram, denote the points $A(-1+i), \;B(1+i),\;M(z).$
Then the vectors $\vec{MA}$ and $\vec{MB}$ are given by the difference $\big((-1+i)-z\big)$ and $\big((1+i)-z\big),\;$ respectively. Absolute value $|z+1-i|=|(-1+i)-z|$ is the lenght of the segment $MA$ (or $AM.$) Analogously holds for $MB.$

- $\left|\frac{(z+1-i)}{(z-1-i)}\right| = 1,$ or equivalently $|z+1-i|=|z-1-i|$ says: *$M$ is equidistant to $A$ and $B$.* So the locus of the points $M(z)$ is the **line bisector of the segment $AB.$** Since the points $A,\;B$ are symmetric about $y-$axis, the locus is this axis. A short  complex equation is $Re(z)=0,$ while an $x,y-$equation is $x=0.$
- $\mathrm{arg}\left[\frac{(z+1+i)}{(z-1-i)}\right] = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ says: *The vectors $\vec{MA}$ and $\vec{MB}$ are orthogonal.* So the locus of points $M(z)$ is the **circle with diameter $AB,$ except the points $A, B.$**
  $B$ is excluded because the denominator cannot be $0,$ and $A$ because it makes the fraction $0,$ but $\mathrm{arg}(w)$ is only defined for $w\neq 0.$